# Undefined e.target.name for toggled state component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm running into errors when trying to set up a list of toggle/switches using useState. All of the initial states work properly and the page renders, however when I click on any toggle I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. I just need to set the state of the one I clicked on. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import Switch from "react-switch"
import styles from './Settings.module.scss'

const Settings = () => {

const [privacyToggles, setprivacyToggles] = useState({
    newContentNotification: false,
    newCommentSubscribed: true,
    newCommentCommented: true,
    publicDonationInfo: false
})

const handleToggleChange = (e) => {

     setprivacyToggles({
         ...privacyToggles,
         [e.target.name]: !privacyToggles[e.target.name]
     })
}

return (
    <>  
        <Dashboard />
        <div className="section">
            <div className="container">
            <h2 className="title is-4">Settings</h2>
                <h3 className="title is-5">Privacy Settings</h3>
                <div className="columns">
                    <div className={styles.toggleList + " column is-full"}>
                        <label className={styles.toggleLabel}>
                            <Switch 
                                onChange={handleToggleChange} 
                                checked={privacyToggles.newContentNotification}
                                name="newContentNotification"
                            />
                            <span className={styles.toggleText}>Receive notification of new content published on the website</span>
                        </label>
                        <label className={styles.toggleLabel}>
                            <Switch 
                                onChange={handleToggleChange} 
                                checked={privacyToggles.newCommentSubscribed}
                                name="newCommentSubscribed"

                            />
                            <span className={styles.toggleText}>Receive notification when somebody adds a comment to an article I am subscribed to</span>
                        </label>
                        <label className={styles.toggleLabel}>
                            <Switch 
                                onChange={handleToggleChange} 
                                checked={privacyToggles.newCommentCommented}
                                name="newCommentCommented"

                            />
                            <span className={styles.toggleText}>Receive notification when somebody adds a comment to an article I commented on</span>
                        </label>
                        <label className={styles.toggleLabel}>
                            <Switch 
                                onChange={handleToggleChange} 
                                checked={privacyToggles.publicDonationInfo}
                                name="publicDonationInfo"
                            />
                            <span className={styles.toggleText}>Publish information about my donations and make them public on my profile</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
)
}
```

export default Settings

Comment: What does `console.log(e)` print?

Comment: Hmm it is weirdly printing the opposite of that toggles state. So if the toggle is unchecked it is printing "true"

Comment: try `value` tag instead of `name`

Comment: I tried just logging the "event", it returns a boolean. You need to also send which input is being toggled so you can correctly update state.

Comment: Can you try doing `handleToggleChange = (...args) =>` and `console.log(args)`?

Comment: For args I get 
(3) [false, Class, undefined]

Comment: If I add the id to each toggle I get this [false, Class, newContentNotification]

Comment: `const handleToggleChange = (...args) => {
        console.log(!args[0])
        
        setprivacyToggles({
            ...privacyToggles,
            [args[2]]: [!args[0]]
        })
    }`

This then sets the toggle to true on first click, but for some reason, doesn't switch it back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` onChange returns the new checked value of the switch, the event, and the `id` prop.

[API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-switch#api)

> `onChange ([checked], [event], [id])` Invoked when the
>   user clicks or drags the switch. It is passed three arguments:
>   checked, which is a boolean that describes the presumed future state
>   of the checked prop (1), the event object (2) and the id prop (3).

If you change your `handleToggleChange` to receive the value and id parameters then you can correlate the field with the changed value.

```
const handleToggleChange = (value, e, id) => {
  setprivacyToggles({
    ...privacyToggles,
    [id]: value
  });
};
```

Then pass the "name" on the `id` prop when attaching the onClick handler

```
<Switch
  onChange={handleToggleChange}
  checked={privacyToggles.newContentNotification}
  id="newContentNotification"
/>
```

[image: Edit react-switch state]

Answer (score 1):

**NEW**
Okay, I've edited the answer.

```
const handleToggleChange = (...args) => {
    setprivacyToggles({
      ...privacyToggles,
      [args[2]]: args[0]
    });
  };
```

**WRONG**
`react-switch` is designed to get the opposite value through `onChange` event.

You can check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-switch).

You should build your own toggle component in order to get your desired result.